# Symfony2 MimeTypeGuesser handling WMV files incorrectly

Tags: php, file, symfony, mime-types, wmv

Update: This is code that handles uploading of video files.

I have a symfony2 project which has 3x MIME type guessers registered at run-time. 
They are:

```
[0] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser Object
[1] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\ContentTypeMimeTypeGuesser Object
[2] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser Object
```

When [FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/MimeType/FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser.php) executes, the method `guess()` gets called, which does:

```
file -b --mime video.wmv 2>/dev/null
```

And the result is:

```
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

Which is incorrect - Per [microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288102), wmv should have a MIME type of:

```
audio/x-ms-wmv
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: How did you get this `video.wmv` ?

Comment: What do you mean? That is the name of the uploaded file ...

Comment: Oh sorry, where did you get the wmv that you upload? Did you download it somewhere? Have you check that, before upload it, the video file has the right mime?

Comment: I found it on the internet! It's a sample/test video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it appears it has something to do w/the videos. Some videos I've found on the internet work while others do not. I'm not sure why, as they are all wmv's - Anyways, this doesn't appear like an issue w/the guesser, but an issue w/the encoding properties or byte sequence of *some* wmvs.

Yahhh microsoft!

Comment: That's what I said :) The problem isn't microsoft, it's the way you retrieve the video from the website. If the website use header mime `audio/x-ms-wmv` your video will have this mime. If the website use the mime `application/octet-stream` to send the video, the wmv will have this mime type. Kind of nightmare, yep.

Comment: Cool - though I have no idea why the content-type of the response would change the mime-type of the downloaded file. That's saying that somehow, the file is being written to and CHANGED based on the responses's content-type? Not sure I buy that or understand it ...

Comment: I didn't find a specific article but this is almost what is described in [this one](http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/news/view/15872/14863/Mimetype-corruption-in-Firefox.html)